# handling multiple string types in new C++ libraries

Tags: c++, string, c++11, libraries

One thing that C++ has is multiple string, or rather character types: `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`. As a result we have different string typedefs: `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `std::u16string` and `std::u32string`, which are distinct string types.

And it doesn't stop there, if we are talking Windows and COM, there's also platform types, like `BSTR`s. And we haven't even started talking about
character encodings.

**If you are building a new library, and one of the requirements was to support all those string types, or character types, how would you do it?** Let's forget about character encodings for now.

I was thinking about this, and I came out with a few options, but none are ideal. Let's assume you have a `registry_key` class, which has to 
support all those character types, and a part of its OM is more or less (only a part of it is illustrated here):

```
class registry_key
{
public:
  registry_key(unspecified_string_type keyname);
  unspecified_string_type name() const; 
  unspecified_string_type path() const; 
}
```

And you would use it like:

```
registry_key key("HKLM\\Software\\Adobe");
std::string name = key.name();
```

But, it has to support the other string types. Also, there isn't a requirement which dictates that the whole `registry_key` has to be consistent as far as character types go, or operate on a single character type. You could call the constructor and pass a `const char*` but get the name of the key as a `u16string`. This is a reflection of the platform underneath, which allows you to call wide (`XxxW`) and narrow (`XxxA`) apis within the same api set. And that behavior is desired.

For the constructor (or things taking arguments) this is trivial, because the type can be deduced. But not for a function that returns strings but doesn't take anything as a input, it can't.

As far as options go, I have:

**1)** Template the whole registry key with a character type, the same way `basic_string`, and other types in the stl did. So you would

```
wregistry_key key(L"HKLM\\Software\\Adobe");
std::wstring name = key.name();

u8registry_key key(u8"HKLM\\Software\\Adobe");
std::u16string name = key.name();
```

The problem is that this doesn't really scale and it's quite horrible if it has to be applied to a lot of types, anything which deals with strings. And in a way it's a poor design choice because some classes aren't even about strings so much, so why pass that in as a template argument in the first place.

**2)** Adopt and use a single string type, like `u16string`, or `u32string`. But as said, that is against the goal.

**3)** Prefix the character type to the function names:

```
registry_key key("HKLM\\Software\\Adobe");
std::string name = key.name();
std::wstring name = key.wname();
std::u16string name = key.u8name();
std::u32string name = key.uname();
```

This is better, but still redundand.

**4)** Make a new string type, which isn't a string type at all. It's in a way a variant that can store different types of strings, and queried and converted to different other types of strings, using user defined conversion operators. So this would be automatic.

```
platform_string str = L"foo";
std::string sstr = str;
std::wstring swstr = str;
std::u16string su16str = str;
str = u"foo";
```

This would enable writing a registry class which could looks like this:

```
class registry_key
{
public:
  registry_key(unspecified_string_type keyname);
  platform_string name() const; 
  platform_string path() const; 
}
```

And you could use it as:

```
registry_key key("HKLM\\Software\\Adobe");
std::string name = key.name();
std::wstring name = key.name();
std::u16string name = key.name();
```

The problem with this is the idea of introducing something that looks like a new string type, even if it isn't really. And it feels broken.

Are there better solutions than **3)** and **4)**? Or a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The customary approach to this type of problem is for the library designer to pick one type of string and use it consistently throughout its interfaces. If you need C compatibility, use a C format string, otherwise a C++ string. Pick the character size you need for the library's functions.

Let the caller of the library handle the string conversion.

Otherwise, you are going to have a mess.

Answer (score 3):

**If you are building a new library, and one of the requirements was to support all those string types, or character types, how would you do it?**

I wouldn't.

Between [std::codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) and [boost::nowide](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/), conversion between the various string formats isn't totally onerous these days.

I'd probably just use UTF-32 internally (RAM is cheap these days, right?) and a UTF-8 public interface. A UTF-16 (using `char16_t`, **not** `wchar_t`) public interface *might* also be justifiable seeing as so many platforms use it internally, especially Windows, though I'd rather avoid such a thing (unless I was being paid for it, perhaps).

`wstring` and `wchar_t` should be avoided wherever possible because of portability issues, as the definition of `wchar_t` is platform dependent. Only character types with explicit widths should be used (eg. `char`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`).

Your option (3) involves quadrupling the size of your API... no thanks!

Your option (4) feels like it would be exceptionally difficult to do well, adding a big chunk of complexity in exchange for a modicum of convenient.

Forcing the caller to do string conversion seems like the simplest, safest and maximally portable way to handle the problem. Solution (2) all the way.

Oh, and the usual http://utf8everywhere.org/ link for completeness.

Comment: The platform-dependent `wchar_t` issue can be circumvented in C++11 which adds the `char16_t` type

Comment: @joe sure, but that's why I mentioned `wchar_t` separately from UTF-16 ;)

Comment: I get that, however you could mention that this alternative already exists (and is meant specifically for UTF-16!)

Comment: @joe I shall clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'd go with others' suggestions and have my library deal with one string type, I'd urge you to have a look at boost.filesystem, in particular the design of the path class
[Boost Filesystem V3 design](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/filesystem/doc/v3_design.html). Basically you have no template class, internally you use just one string type, and then provide templated members that accept whatever string type you decide and convert to the internal representation.

Comment: the problem with the boost's path is that it's very localized and isolated, it doesn't scale if you have to do it in a lot of places, in my library I have a great big lots of functions that return strings, if it has to be done for every single one of them, it's really quite unusable

Comment: in this case the only solution that scales is to use a single type and let the client do the conversion when needed. The actual type should depend on the platform to avoid unneeded conversions (std::string on Linux which uses UTF-8 usually, std::u16string or std::wstring on Windows), thus something like:

#ifdef WIN32
typedef std::wstring string_type;
#else
typedef std::string string_type;
#endif